# Add object to object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like below:

```
var _names = { 
    'name1@gmail.com' : { 
        'bob@gmail.com' : {
            channel: '1234', 
            from: 'bob'
        }
    },
    'name2@gmail.com' : { 
        'dan@gmail.com' : {
            channel: '53345',
            from: 'dan'
        }
    }
};
```

How could i add the following to name1@gmail.com:

```
        'judy@gmail.com' : {
            channel: '23233', 
            from: 'judy'
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you make it more localized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add it using the square bracket notation. Since your key names are not valid JavaScript variable names, you cannot use the dot notation.

```
_names['name1@gmail.com']['judy@gmail.com'] = {
    channel: '23233', 
    from: 'judy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
_names['name1@gmail.com']['judy@gmail.com'] = {
    channel: '23233', 
    from: 'judy'
};
```